# Parse mysql results in PHP and return to Flot

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling data from a MySQL database and plotting with Flot.  My problem is in our DB design.
I have 1 table that contains the following columns:

1. ID (auto incremented) (key)
2. Timestamp
3. SensorData (looks like: 34534.3 32452.4 23454.6 6523.45 67546.4 2233)

I would like to parse out my sensor data so I can create Flot plots with individual sensor data.  Right now, I am able to plot the ID vs Timestamp and that works.  Here is my code:

```
    <html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Flot Examples</title>
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

<?php

    $server = "www.freesql.org";
    $user="username";
    $password="password";
    $database = "database";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

    $query = "SELECT Id, localtme FROM varia";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array($row['Id'],$row['localtme']);
    }
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>;

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ dataset1 ]);
});
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't help you.. all we can get from your sample is that you have a bunch of timestamps (localtme?) and some ids associated with those timestamps. We can't read your mind, so can't tell you how to "parse out sensor data".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  So inside my "SensorData" column, there are multiple entries.  The first is Temp, second is pressure, etc.  I am trying to setup one web page with multiple plots.  First plot would be LocalTime vs Temp.  Second plot would be LocalTime vs Pressure, etc.  But I don't know how to parse out all the data contained in the column SensorData in order to generate the plots.  Make more sense or am I just confusing everyone?

Comment: ah. You should pre-process that column and split each of those individual values into their own dedicated column. e.g. [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the design.

Comment: When you say "Pre Process", am I able to do that from my PHP page above?  The DataRecorder that send this sensor data to the MySQL DB is hard coded and streams in real time.  I am trying to have my Flot graph plot in realtime also.  Any way I can pull this off using the php code above?

Comment: then I'd suggest you have the sensor stream to a temporary table, then use some code to translate the "all-in-one" temporary data into a permanent table on a scheduled basis, so that you always have nicely normalized source data to work with. even a simple trigger in the temp table could do this for you.

Comment: Do you have a specific "term" that I could search for?  I am unfamiliar with this process.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html ? capture the insert event in mysql, then do some process to split that data field into individual values in separate fields in the db.